# Set wallpaper and lock screen's background as two different photos?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, lock-screens, wallpaper

Current when I choose a photo to be set as wallpaper, my lock screen's background is automatically changed to be this new one.

I want the lockscreen to keep its old background, how can I do that?

ps.

I'm using Google Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Android 4.0.4 and above should let you change both separatelly.

Comment: My Android version is 4.1.1

Comment: Indeed I have googled and see other users can have the option to set so but on my phone, I cannot find that

Answer (score 1):

Although I am on another device with another android version (HTC Desire HD / ROM: JellyTime R9, Android 4.2.2) I think the problem may be the same.

In the Gallery app I can only set the images as background. But I can set a different lock screen background image in system settings. I think this option depends on the specific Launcher/Lockscreen you use and are also valid in stock roms. I am using NovaLauncher and I can only set a different lockscreen image that way as far as I know.

Look in Settings → UI → Lock screen → Background → Custom image (maybe different wording — I only have the German version here).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. But what you can do is download a third party locker such as [GO Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock).

Comment: On Android 4.1.1 you can set a different wallpaper without 3rd party apps.

Comment: How would GoLocker help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do, supposing you're on a stock ROM:

1. Open your Gallery app.
2. Select the image you want to set as background.
3. Hit *Menu* and you should see an option *Set as*, click on it.
4. You should end with several options in which you can find *Home screen*, *Lock screen* and *Home and lock screens*.
5. Select the option you want to set your wallpaper to.

[image: Screenshot of Set as menu]

If you have a custom ROM, you should check the forums of that ROM to see if its supports this.

Comment: Sorry Peter, on my phone, after selecting the image in Gallery, I only have options: 1-set as wallpaper, 2-set as contact. No option for lock screen indeed.

Comment: Do you have a stock ROM or are you using a custom ROM (Cyanogenmod for example)?

Comment: I use the original phone without making anything changed related to the ROM as you call it

Answer (score 0):

I had  a bit of trouble setting the lock screen pic. I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace Q i827 (Appeal in the U.S.) & I had to first find a pic I wanted, then I had to hit the menu button a couple of times to find the 'set as' button. At first I only hit it once, & no 'save as' button appeared. But after hitting it again, it popped up. After clicking on the 'set as', I had the option of selecting the lock screen or wallpaper.  This is for gingerbread 2.3.6.